Automatic Redirect Based on Browser Language
I have a website that is available in multiple languages. Currently, the index.html file instantly redirects the user to the English homepage by using the line below:
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=./en/home.html" />

However, I want it to instead check for the Browser language and do the following:

If the browser language is French, redirect to the French homepage
If the browser language is German, redirect to the German homepage
If the browser language is Persian, redirect to the Persian homepage
If the browser language is English or anything else, redirect to the English homepage.

Problem is, I have no idea how to do this, so I'd appreciate some help! And yes, I could technically replace the index.html with a manual language selector, bur for the sake of UX I want it to be automatic.
Also, I want to avoid using cookies if possible, as having to put a cookie popup on this site (which is meant to be a personal portfolio) ruins the intuitiveness.
